# why the setChangeListener of CheckBox not work

Tags: android

I wanna add Checkbox dynamically based on topping list using below code, but the onChangeListener doesn't work and I can't access these checkboxs after adding them to layout, why is it and what can I do to fix? Any solution will be appreciated.

```
 for (topping in viewModel.burgerToppingList) {
                val checkBox = CheckBox(this)
                checkBox.text = topping
                checkBox.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, isChecked ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "stateChange", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        viewModel.addSum(0.75f)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        viewModel.minusSum(0.75f)
                    }
                }
                binding.llcToppingList.addView(checkBox)
                viewModel.checkBoxList?.add(checkBox)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: **OnCheckedChangeListener**

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(   { 
  buttonView, isChecked ->
   // code for logic
       }
    )
```